# Beam Dataflow job stuck after upgrading the Apache Beam version from 2.27.0 to 2.32.0

Tags: pip, google-cloud-dataflow, python-3.7, apache-beam

Currently I am in a process of upgrading the Apache Beam version from 2.27.0 to 2.32.0 but when I start my jobs on Dataflow runner the job stucks during the worker-startup and it never finish installing dependencies. The python version is 3.7

This is what I see in the logs

```
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime
```

After initial analysis it looks like this is the issue with pip dependencies backtracking and it keeps on downloading and installing dependencies. These are some warnings in the logs

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of google-auth to determine which version is compatible with other requirements.
```

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead:
```

This is the setup.py for the Beam

```
import setuptools

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    "numpy==1.21.4",
    "pandas==0.25.3",
    "dateparser==1.1.0",
    "python-dateutil==2.8.2",
    "pytz==2021.3",
    "google-api-core==1.14.0",
    "google-cloud-storage==1.36.1",
    "fastavro==0.22.10",
]

setuptools.setup(
    name="data-workflows",
    version="0.1.0",
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

The pipelines used to run fine in the Beam version 2.27.0. I am not sure if these warnings are the cause of the issue. Could someone please help me to identify the root cause of this problem?

Comment: how do you execute this command? I hope inside the virtual environment,

Comment: Yes the airflow job creates a pod and the dataflow pipeline is triggered